# SAS macro using a list of variable as parameter

Tags: macros, sas

I would like to pass a list of variables to the macro for further analysis but only the last one get pass.

```
%macro try(varlist=%str(gender race agegroup));
prroc freq data=test;
table &varlist;
run;
%mend;
```

results:

```
proc freq data=test;
  table agegroup;
run;
```

not as excpected as:

```
proc freq data=test;
 table gender race agegroup;
run;
```

Comment: it seems all fine to me , just change prroc to proc - but this is not an issue, as SAS will take care of it. how are you executing the macro? I hope it is %try;

Comment: Agree, looks good to me. You don’t need to use %str.  Show your macro call, and the log with mprint option turned on.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! Actually,  my original question was simplified by omitting the group. Proc freq; table (&var) * group; run;   Adding ()  around &var solved the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, you type PRROC instead PROC...

Comment: Thanks, PPROC was a typo.